# Find the total amount of beads used if there is twice the number of large beads than a small one?

Tags: statistics

I had a test a few days ago (year nine level) and my friends and I were stuck on this question:

"Bill is making a bracelet using small and large beads. There are twice the number of large beads than small beads. A large bead weighs $120$mg and a small bead weighs $80$mg. The total weight of the beads used is $32$grams. How many beads were used altogether?"

Our answers varied from $3$ to $300$, but none of us got it right. We didn't get to know the answer either. Is there a way to solve this question? 
Thank you.

--

edit: Thank you, everyone! I can't believe most of us got such a simple question wrong. The teacher must've accidentally marked one of my friend's answer (they wrote 300) as incorrect. It makes much more sense now.

Comment: Why do you say none of you got it right?

Comment: We all got the question wrong but the teachers didn't tell us what the correct answers were. The teacher must've corrected one of my friend's answer wrong, as it was definitely the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given information:

- There are $n$ small beads, each weighing $80$mg
- There are $2n$ large beads, each weighing $120$mg
- There are $n+2n$ beads, altogether weighing $32000$mg

From that, we get:

$$n\cdot80+2n\cdot120=32000 \implies 320n=32000 \implies n=100 \implies n+2n=300$$

Answer (score 0):

$s$ denotes small and $l$ denotes large beads.

$$s,l=?$$

---

number of beads:
$$s\times 2=l$$

weights in mili-gram:
$$80\times s + 120 \times l=320$$

---

$$80\times s+120\times2\times s=32000$$

---

$$320 \times s =32000$$

---

$$s=100$$
$$l=200$$

Answer (score 0):

Call the number of small beads $s$, the number of large beads $l$ and the weight in milligrams $w$, then you know:
$$
l=2s\\
w=32000\\
w=120l+80s
$$
That's a fairly simple set of equations.

First step id to insert the first two pieces of information in the third, that gives:
$$
32000=240s+80s=320s
$$
A simple divison now gives $s$ multiplying by $2$ will then give you $l$ and adding $s$ and $l$ gives the total number of beads.

Answer (score 0):

This question has an easy answer for kids under 9th grade: think the beads grouped. As you have twice the big beads than the small ones each group will have three beads and will weight 320mg.

The whole bracelet weights 32g so you will have 100 groups or, if you prefer, 300 beads of which 100 small and 200 large.